# Free a pointer equal to a malloc pointer

Tags: c

I'm having trouble understanding some of the free() behavior.

```
int* ptr1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof (int)*10);
int* ptr2 = ptr1;
free(ptr2);
```

Is the `free(ptr2)` going to delete my array as I want ?

What if I do :

```
int** ptr1 = (int**)malloc(sizeof (int)*10);
int* ptr2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof (int));
*ptr2 = 10;
ptr1[0] = ptr2;
free(ptr1);
```

Is this code correct ? Will `free(ptr1)` will also delete the space of ptr2 ?

Thanks

Comment: In the first example, either one, but not both. The only information that you give to `free` is the pointer's value. In the second peculiar contrivance, only one memory space is returned to the system.

Comment: there is a tool called `valgrind` that I suggest you look up and start using. It will show you any memory leaks in your program (if there are any).

Comment: Why is code using `sizeof(int)*10` to compute the memory needed for some pointers in `int** ptr1 = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);`.  I'd expect `int** ptr1 = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int *)*10);`

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: [malloc()ing](https://makecleanandmake.com/2014/07/26/how-to-malloc-the-right-way/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int* ptr1 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
int* ptr2 = ptr1;
free(ptr2);
```

That is fine, `ptr2` contains the same value as `ptr1`, and thus the memory you passed to `malloc()` is `free()`d.

```
int** ptr1 = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
int* ptr2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
*ptr2=10;
ptr1[0]=ptr2;
free(ptr1);
```

That is not fine. You are storing the value of `ptr2` in the `ptr1` array, but not freeing it. You want:

```
int** ptr1 = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*10);
int* ptr2 = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
*ptr2=10;
ptr1[0]=ptr2; 
...
free(ptr1[0]);
free(ptr1);
```

Note I have also changed the `malloc()` to allocate 10 pointers to `int`, not merely ten `int`s (which may not be the same size).

Finally note that you [don't need to cast the return value from `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) in C. I haven't fixed that for you as it is not a problem in itself and is unrelated to your question, but it is (arguably) bad style.

Comment: Thanks ! If I define a struct with `int tab[10]` in it. Then create this struct with malloc and delete it with free. Should I worry about my tab ?

Comment: @Kenshin: If you allocate a `struct` will `malloc()` and free it with `free()` this will free the allocation you made with `malloc()` but not free anything referenced by the structure. The simple rule is for every allocation, there has to be a matched `free()` - nice and simple. There's no concept of a 'recursive' free.

Comment: Yes but my tab wasn't created with a malloc. So Is my tab considered part of my struct or should I delete it somehow ?

Comment: @Kenshin if you create the struct with `malloc()` but not the `int tab[10]` then you should only `free()` the `struct`, and not `free()` the `int tab[10]`. The rules are simple - match `malloc()` (and anything else that allocates on the heap) and `free()`

Comment: @Kenshin: in general it's useful to remember that C is quite stupid and does nothing 'behind your back'. Compare with (e.g.) Java. Some consider this to be a feature not a bug.

Comment: You're right that you don't need to cast `malloc()` return value, but it's not just that it's bad style if you do, it can hide errors (has to do with forgetting to include a header or something I think?).

Comment: @RastaJedi click on the link I put in the text and it will lead you to a long discussion.

Comment: @abligh yeah that's a good link; I linked him to it in a comment in OP too. It's also good that it notes it's usually better to do `sizeof *array` instead of `sizeof (int)` in case the type changes. I never used to use this style until I read it here on SO. @Kenshin yeah and I know this only about C but the same can be said about C++: match every `malloc()`/`free()`, `new`/`delete`, and `new[]`/`delete[]`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no, respectively.

Also note that `malloc(sizeof(int)*10);` in the second example will work, but it will not necessarily allocate space for ten pointers.

---

To explain what happens in the first example, after the assignment to `ptr2` you have something like this:

```
+------+
| ptr1 | ---\
+------+     \      +----------------------------+
              >---> | memory allocated by malloc |
+------+     /      +----------------------------+
| ptr2 | ---/
+------+
```

Both variables contain the same value, the pointer returned by `malloc`, so you can use either of them to access the allocated memory.

For the second question, what you have is something like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+-----+
| ptr1[0] | ptr1[1] | ptr1[2] | ... |
+---------+---------+---------+-----+
  |
  |
  v
+----------------------------+
| memory allocated by malloc |
+----------------------------+
  ^
  |
  |
+------+
| ptr2 |
+------+
```

When you free the memory pointer to by `ptr1` that only frees that memory, the memory pointed to by `ptr2` is still there and accessible through `ptr2`.

Comment: This question is off topic, but did you use a tool to draw this figures?

Comment: @MartinEttl Nope, did it by hand. :)

Comment: Then you might take a look at [this discussion](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126630/creating-diagrams-in-ascii/127782#127782). There are plenty of tools available.

Answer (score 2):

`malloc` and `free` do not know about your data structures.  All they know about is blobs of bytes.

As a general rule, there should be a one-to-one relationship between your `malloc` and `free` calls.  (There are plenty of exceptions, but it's a good general rule.)

It is never the case that a single call to `free` will simultaneously free two separate blocks allocated by two calls to `malloc`.

So, as others have said, the answers to your questions are "Yes" and "No".

Answer (score 0):

> Is the free(ptr2) going to delete my array as I want ?

I think the term `delete` cannot be used here. The [GNU manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Freeing-after-Malloc.html) says :

> When you no longer need a block that you got with malloc, use the
>   function free to make the block available to be allocated again.

However free doesn't set pointer automatically to NULL because the function return type itself is `void`.  Also,

> Freeing a block alters the contents of the block. Do not expect to
>   find any data (such as a pointer to the next block in a chain of
>   blocks) in the block after freeing it.

I am not spurring a debate on whether you should set the pointer to NULL after freeing it. However,I felt tempted to post this example which crashes and burns :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int* ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
    int* ptr2 = ptr1;
    free(ptr2);
    if(ptr2!=NULL)
    {
        printf("ptr is %p\n",ptr2); // still printf
        printf("Enter a number for ptr2 :");
        scanf("%d",ptr2);
        printf("Value pointed to by ptr2 : %d\n",*ptr2);
        printf("Value pointed to by ptr1 : %d\n",*ptr1);
    }
    else
        printf("Ptr2 pointed to null");
    printf("Size of ptr1 : %d\n",sizeof(ptr1));

    if(ptr1==NULL)
        printf("ptr1 NULL\n");
    printf("Enter a number for ptr1 :");
    scanf("%d",ptr1);
    printf("Value pointed to by ptr1 : %d\n",*ptr1);
    printf("Value pointed to by ptr2 : %d\n",*ptr2);

    free(ptr1);
    if(ptr1==NULL)
        printf("ptr1 freed\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
ptr is 0x1c92010
Enter a number for ptr2 :4
Value pointed to by ptr2 : 4
Value pointed to by ptr1 : 4
Size of ptr1 : 8
Enter a number for ptr1 :1
Value pointed to by ptr1 : 1
Value pointed to by ptr2 : 1
*** glibc detected *** ./testp: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001c92010 ***
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```